# How do I get the EventArgs of my Custom OnClickListener

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, onclicklistener

I needed to make a Custom Click Listener but I'm having some trouble with the syntax.

This is more of a c# question as I am trying to implement this on Xamarin.Android

Here is my Custom Click Listener

```
public class OnSingleClickListener : Java.Lang.Object,  View.IOnClickListener
{
    private readonly Action onSingleClick;

    public OnSingleClickListener()
    {
    }

    public OnSingleClickListener(Action onSingleClick)
    {
        this.onSingleClick = onSingleClick;
    }

    public void OnClick(View v)
    {
        onSingleClick?.Invoke();     
    }
}
```

In my Fragment, I implemented:

```
button.SetOnClickListener(new OnSingleClickListener(() 
                => OnButtonClicked(HowDoIPassEventArgs?)));
```

And then

```
private void OnButtonClicked(HowDoIGetTheseEventArgs?)
{
    ViewModel.buttonCommand.Execute(HowDoIGetTheseEventArgs?);
}
```

How can I get the EventArgs from this click in my new method 'OnButtonClicked'?

/////////
edit: This is how it was implemented before --

```
button.Click += OnButtonClicked;

private void OnButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs args) //I want these same EventArgs
{
    ViewModel.buttonCommand.Execute(args);
}
```

I just want to implement it the same but with my new Custom Click Listener

Comment: What `EventArgs` ? you need to create them by yourself prolly by getting View inside OnClick and putting it there ...

Comment: also how what is  `ViewModel.buttonCommand` ... how it is defined? ... It's prolly `ICommand` so the arguments are not depends on "who" cliecked but on some binding ... so proly you should just call `ViewModel.buttonCommand.Execute(textView1.getText())` or whatever it expects to get

Comment: @Selvin I edited my question, can you please help me?

Comment: So what is wrong with Sushil answers? with usage like `button.SetOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(OnButtonClicked));`

Comment: you may short it to `class OnClickListener : Java.Lang.Object, View.IOnClickListener {
 readonly EventHandler handler;
 public OnClickListener(EventHandler handler){
  this.handler = handler;
 }
 public void OnClick(View v)
    {
        handler?.Invoke(v, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}`   as I'm pretty sure  Xamarin.Android is sending Empty EventArgs in such cases

Comment: Ok thats helpful, but what is the syntax for this? button.SetOnClickListener(new OnSingleClickListener(() 
                => OnButtonClicked(HowDoIPassEventArgs?)));

Comment: as OnButtonClicked is defined as void OnButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs args) you may use your code like  `button.SetOnClickListener(new OnSingleClickListener(() => OnButtonClicked(whatEver, null)));` I don't get what you wana achevie (and of course then `Action` should be `Action<object, EventArgs>`)

Comment: Ah! thank you for help I'm understanding it now, it all 'clicked' for me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an `EventHandler` vs. an `Action` and define the custom `EventArgs` subclass that you wish to pass in the handler.

```
public class OnClickListener : Java.Lang.Object, View.IOnClickListener
{
    public class ClickEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        object someObjectYouWantToPass; // replace with a strong object type that you are passing
        public ClickEventArgs(object someObjectYouWantToPass) => this.someObjectYouWantToPass = someObjectYouWantToPass;
    }

    readonly EventHandler handler;
    public OnClickListener(EventHandler handler) => this.handler = handler;

    public void OnClick(View v)
    {
        handler?.Invoke(v, new ClickEventArgs(null)); // replace null w/ your custom event object(s)
    }
}
```